# Filtering NSArray of NSDictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array like this:

```
NSArray* myArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"123",@"imageid",@"Jeff",@"imagename", nil],
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"234",@"imageid",@"Sophie",@"imagename", nil],
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"456",@"imageid",@"David",@"imagename", nil]
                      , nil];
```

I wanna get a target array which contains like :
{
 123,234,456
}

How to do this using `NSPredicate`？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You may not need `NSPredicate` for this.

```
NSArray *targetArray = [myArray valueForKey:@"imageid"];
```

**Update:**
For better understanding of valueForKey, please refer [apple documentation of NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)